# Is AI the right tool for solving walking?

Tags: training

Modern robots walk like they had a heart attack and then a stroke... twice. Everyone in AI fiercely believes that the higher number of neurons (or the quality of training with smaller number of neurons) is the solution and things will definitely improve after pumping in more neurons and more time.

Everyone talks about humans and how many neurons we have and how our babies need time to learn to walk.

Meanwhile horse babies are born and start running right away after a minute or so. They have less neurons than we do.

Ants jump out of their eggs and zoom around like crazy, their brains have only 250k neurons.

Xeno bots were moving around repurposing their protrusions for swimming, sensing the environment, changing directions and such - those are individual cells, no brains, no neurons.

Is AI really a way to solving organism movement problem? It seems like a completely wrong tool for the task.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, for any complex problem there is only one solution: AI.

Humanoid robots are just starting. Yes, they are here let say 30 years in some cases but it was only hard-coded attempts to make robots.

First true case of useful robot was introduced by Tesla one year ago and first demo showed yesterday.

This is the first real case when real AI was used and not just hard-coded  programming. Tesla AI - which has been developed for cars - FSD.

You can watch on youtube how increasingly better FSD has become in last few months. Everything is recorded. The same speed of improvement will be visible on Tesla Bot.

So yes. This is extremely complex problem therefore only AI can solve this.

Boston Dynamics tried this hard-coded way (20 years of trying) and they failed.
Tesla nailed it when they was able to put together walking robot in 8 months.

And the positive impact is that AI of Tesla Bot will impact FSD and FSD will impact AI of Tesla Bot. The synergies will run in both directions. It's inevitable.

*> Meanwhile horse babies are born and start running right away after a minute or so. They have less neurons than we do.*

Number of neurons is correlated to number of organs and complexity what organism is capable of + number of environments where can life. Variation of movements for humanoids are far more complex than variation of movements and capabilities of horses.

And movements for humanoids must reflect also general thinking - how to use tools. Humanoids are tool makers and every tool category has different set of movements. So if you want to solve walking for humanoids you have to build in tool usage what has impact on walk movements.